# GWCode Categories displays nothing

Tags: gwcode-categories

I can't get a simple GWCode Categories tag to display anything.

```
{exp:gwcode_categories channel="general_areas"}
{cat_name}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

But this displays the list just fine:

```
{exp:channel:categories
    channel="general_areas"
    style="nested"
}
{category_name}
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

I'm stumped.

Comment: This may be an easy one but have you ensured it's installed properly? What version of GWCC and EE are you running?

Comment: It shows up in the installed Plugins list. Running v1.8.9 with EE 2.5.5.

Comment: Very strange. I can't recreate this issue. It outputs fine for me every time and I have the same versions installed. Are you wrapping the tags in anything which could be causing a problem? Are you getting any errors returned?

Comment: There is nothing in the template other than that tag. I just tried turning on template debugging but it does not display. Something fishy is going on here!

Comment: Got the template debugger working. No errors but it does show that GWCode is return no results. I added {if no_results}No results{/if} to the tag and it does display "No results". I don't understand why GWCode Categories would show no results when the EE categories tag shows them just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working. This is an MSM setup and it seems you must provide a site id to the tag.